# Upload a video to Facebook without posting on wall from iOS

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I upload a  video to my Facebook album without posting it on my wall from iOS?

I tried to use the "no_story" flag that works with photos.

Answer (score 0):

There's no flag or option to prevent a story appearing about a new video upload

Comment: What I want to accomplish is a custom story with a video uploaded from iOS. If I have an image I can post it to the Facebook album without publish it on the wall, and then use it for my custom story. So this can't be done with a video without posting it to the wall and then as a custom story?